# Add UIButton over AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, overlay, avcapture

I am trying to create a overlay on top of `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

I tried the following, but the result is not what I expected as the button's title is not visible:

```
let previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.avCaptureSession)
previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)



//Add Button
let captureButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100 , 100))
captureButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
captureButton.setTitle("Capture", forState: .Normal)
captureButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
captureButton.addTarget(self, action: "actionCapture:", forControlEvents: .TouchDragInside)

previewLayer.addSublayer(captureButton.layer)
```

Here is a screenshot of the current state:

[image: screenshot of the current state]

Comment: What is the result? Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: @the4kman  I have added the screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `previewLayer` to a separate view's sublayer. That way, you can easily add other subviews above your main view.

```
let previewView = UIView(frame: view.frame)
view.addSubview(previewView)

previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

[...]

view.addSubview(captureButton)
```

Comment: I tried this, but the view I added on top of the previewView only appeared for a second then disappeared